# Задача с Codility. Математика

Tags: javascript, c++, математика, дискретная-математика

В ряд стоит класс из N учеников. Нужно сфотографировать студентов, но по эстетическим соображениям вы хотите, чтобы они были упорядочены в порядке роста. Чтобы достичь этого, вы можете указать смежной группе студентов изменить свои позиции. Ваша цель состоит в том, чтобы найти минимальное количество студентов, стоящих в смежной группе, которые после перестановки своих позиций приведут к тому, что весь ряд будет упорядочен по высоте.

Текущее расположение учащихся задается массивом A, в котором элемент A<sub>K</sub> записывает высоту ученика в позиции K. После перестановки ученики должны быть отсортированы в порядке неубывания высоты. Т.е. A<sub>P</sub> ≤ A<sub>P+1</sub> для любого 0 ≤ P < N-1.

Например, если массив A имеет следующий вид:

```
A [0] = 1
A [1] = 2
A [2] = 6
A [3] = 5
A [4] = 5
A [5] = 8
A [6] = 9
```

То наименьшая группа студентов, которую нужно переставить, - это A [2..4], длины 3. После перегруппировки этой группы получим [1,2,5,5,6,8,9], которая находится в правильном порядке .
Любая другая перестановка, включающая смежную группу менее чем из трех студентов, не приведет к правильной сортировке результирующей строки.

Решение должно содержать функцию, которая получает массив A, содержащий разность роста студента и фотографа, и возвращает минимальное число студентов, стоящих в смежной группе, после сортировки которой весь массив окажется отсортированным . Если массив студентов уже упорядочен, функция должна вернуть 0.

Например, для описанного выше массива A функция должна возвращать 3.

```
Предположим, что:
 1. N - целое число в диапазоне [1. 100 000]
 2. каждый элемент массива А является целым числом в диапазоне [1. 100 000 000].
```

Хотел бы видеть ваше решение, желательно на JS (я его изучаю).

Comment: Первая мысль - тупо в лоб - сортируем; искомый диапазон - между первым и последним несовпадениями неотсортированного и отсортированного массива... Но это - O(n log n) + память O(n).

Comment: @vp_arth Вопрос понятен, и у меня другое решение. Прошу переоткрыть.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky Вопрос понятен, и у меня другое решение. Прошу переоткрыть.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, у вас достаточно репутации чтобы править вопрос. В текущем виде - это оффтоп. Здесь не место для готовых решений задачек. Вопрос не то, чтобы непонятен - вопроса нет.

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо за совет, правку внёс. А решить интересную задачку - не грех, даже здесь. Тем более что вопросов по алгоритмам почти нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая мысль - тупо в лоб - сортируем; искомый диапазон - между первым и последним несовпадениями неотсортированного и отсортированного массива... Но это - O(n log n) + память O(n). Хотя раз `n` до 100000 - это очень немного.

Код на C++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr int N = 100000;
    vector<int> A(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        A[i] = rand();
    for(int i = rand(); i >= 0; --i)
        A[i] = i;
    for(int i = N - rand(); i < N; ++i)
        A[i] = i;
    vector<int> B(A);
    sort(B.begin(),B.end());
    int b, e;
    for(b = 0; b < N && A[b]==B[b]; ++b);
    if (b == N) { cout << "0\n"; return 0; }
    for(e = N-1; e >= 0 && A[e]==B[e]; --e);
    cout << (e-b+1) << "\n";
}
```

Ну, чтоб реально посмотреть-проверить - вот:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    constexpr int N = 10;
    vector<int> A(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        A[i] = rand()%10;
    for(int i = rand()%4; i >= 0; --i)
        A[i] = i;
    for(int i = N - rand()%4; i < N; ++i)
        A[i] = i;
    vector<int> B(A);
    sort(B.begin(),B.end());
    int b, e;
    for(b = 0; b < N && A[b]==B[b]; ++b);
    if (b == N) { cout << "0\n"; return 0; }
    for(e = N-1; e >= 0 && A[e]==B[e]; --e);
    cout << (e-b+1) << "\n";
    for(auto i: A) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
    for(auto i: B) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

Получаются результаты вроде

```
7
0 1 5 6 6 4 1 5 1 9 
0 1 1 1 4 5 5 6 6 9
```